# elasticsearch NEST library match multiple words

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a class named "IndexModel", and I have already created the index for this type.  This has two records, and the values of name property in these records are "test hello world" and "testhello world".  I'm using following query to search the records by the Name property:

```
var query = new MatchQuery()
{
    Field = Property.Path<IndexModel>(it=>it.Name),
    Query = "test world",
    Operator = Operator.And,
    Lenient = true,
    MaxExpansions = 2,
    CutoffFrequency = 1.31,
    Boost=2.1,
    Fuzziness = 1.8,
    Slop = 2
};

var result = client.Search<IndexModel>(s=>s.Query(query));
```

However, only one result is returned - "test hello world".  I'd also like to match the record with the name of "testhello world".  How can I do this?

Comment: adding * to the beginning or the end may help